# Select table with same id but different category in the same table

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause

I tried and read but I still can't figure out how to handle this request:

I have a table like this:

```
id_news  id_category   id_opinion   
113      5             152 
112      5             152 
152      8             0 
153      8             0 
114      5             153
115      5             153
```

I want to call my post where id_category 5 & 8 and id_news same like id_opinion I'm doing this statement but I don't think it's correct

```
select * from news where id_category = '5' AND id_category='8' AND id_news = id_opinion
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the output you want based on given sample data?

Comment: I want to show news that have same id_opinion and id_news

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `OR` for `id_category`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE (id_category = '5' OR id_category='8') AND id_news = id_opinion;
```

Another option would be to use `IN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE id_category IN ('5', '8') AND id_news = id_opinion;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN operator for filter id_category 5 & 8:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE id_category IN ('5', '8') AND id_news = id_opinion;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work.

```
SELECT c.`id_news` as `newsId`,c.id_category as `Category`,c.id_opinion as `opinion`,d.`id_news` as `newsId1`,d.id_category as `Category1`,d.id_opinion as `opinion1` 
from news as c 
JOIN news as d on c.`id_news` = d.`id_opinion`
where c.id_category in(5,8)
```